# How to ensure privacy while using the crystal ball?

Tags: communication, secret-society, precognition

I am forming a super secret coven or S.S.C. unit to overthrow the magistrates in Salem before New Year's Eve of 1963. The only means of communication as well as identification is the crystal ball, these crystal balls are made of 91% glass and 9% gelatin (muahahaha!)

Each SSC member shall replace their right eyeball with a crystal ball of the same size, and the **operation manual as follows:**

- The crystal ball will glow when receiving call
- The crystal ball will vibrate when receiving call while put in silent mode (I will upgrade to accelerometer later)
- User must rub the crystal ball to pick up call
- User must stare into the crystal ball to see clearer picture
- The sound is transferred via bone conduction

**Working principle as follow:**

- The user is able to watch live streaming of events ahead of time. So user can fast forward or rewind the precognition by rubbing the crystal ball in a certain direction.

**Question:**
Since the only magic is the crystal ball meaning everybody including a 3-year old can operate, my question is how to ensure privacy while using the crystal ball? (For example, if it fell into the police hands and I don't want them to eavesdrop.)

Comment: How do you _make_ the call?

Comment: 'The User must stare into the crystal ball to see clearer picture'??? Errr how exactly does that work? Sure you removed the eye ball from it's socket and presumably 'magic' causes the ball to link with and sustain the optic nerve but staring involves consciously using the muscles around the eyeball to change the shape of the lens so it fixes on a distant object (OUTSIDE THE EYE.) For your idea to work the user would have to remove the crystal ball from it's eye socket & hold it out in front of the users working eye.  Which is a tad suspicious/icky if done in your local restaurant etc.

Comment: You'll also need a skilled surgeon to perform the operation. If it was me? I'd rather just have a fancy key chain thanks very much. Or maybe you can remove a testicle instead since that woudl be less handicapping/difficult? You'd still have a problem taking calls in a public place though. 'Sorry officer my testicle was vibrating.' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the old days when my parents had a land line phone, when they didn't want to be bothered by incoming calls they would simply lift the receiver and leave it raised, ensuring that the line was busy for whoever attempted to call.

You can do the same: disable receiving calls when it's not the time of receiving calls.

If you don't get calls, they can't look into your eye and see what you are receiving.

Comment: How do you know when it's time to receive a call? Perhaps the coven only has a pre-determined schedule for calls. Unless a witch is caught *during* a call and preventing from disabling the device, the investigators can't get their hands on a usable device. That introduces several possible conflicts to the plot: the call schedule must be secured, the members must be in a secure area before answering the call, the method for enabling / disabling the device must be chosen so that the witch can do it even while fleeing from or defending themselves but not so simple that non-members can do it, too.

Answer (score 4):

**PIN lock/unlock**

Each Crystal ball has a unique combination that is set by the owner, this is required to unlock the Crystal Ball to answer a call.

Could be a number sequence, could be spoken, could be a unique gesture traced on the ball etc.

Answer (score 0):

## SIM Lock

If your crystal ball is lost or stolen, you go to poisonedapple dot com or make a quick call and inform it. The company will remotely turn that magic crystal ball into a magic crystal brick, rendering it dark and useless forever.

Some thieves might be smart enough to do a hard factory reset and change the SIM codes, but then they'll have a brand new device with a different number and thus won't be able to use your data.

Comment: This works for lost crystal balls but not when it is forcibly removed by the Inquisitor while you are restrained in a prison cell, preventing you from contacting anyone to disable the thing.

Comment: @EngineerToast neither does any other method ;) rubber hose hacking is a thing too, capable of defeating any defense mechanism you put on it.